# Writing lists of data to a text file column by column

Tags: python, numpy, output

I have 3 lists, a,b,c how can I write them to a text file in the format of table (rows and columns) as this:

```
 time(s) voltage(V)    current(A)
       0    0000000000      101101010
       0.0005   0000110001  101011000
      0.001 0001100000      101011000
```

I have tried to write:

```
powdata=open("powdata.txt","w")
for i in a:
   powdata.write("%s\n"%i)
for j in b:
   powdata.write("%s\n"%j)

powdata.close()
```

Unfortunately this kind of codes just writes data in the text file vertically I mean not like the suggested table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use pandas?
 e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time(s)' : [0, 0.005, 0.001], 'voltage(V)' : ['0000000000','0000110001','0001100000'], 'current(A)' : ['101101010','101011000','101011000']})
```

or, if

```
a = [0, 0.005, 0.001] 
b = ['0000000000','0000110001','0001100000']
c = ['101101010','101011000','101011000']
```

you could just do

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time(s)' : a, 'voltage(V)' : b, 'current(A)' : c})
```

then

```
df.to_csv('powdata.txt', sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful, but it also writes the number of value beside it in the text file like [0,1,2,........],is their any chance not to write it?

Comment: ah yes, simply use df.to_csv('powdata.txt', sep='\t', index=False) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to interleave the lists

```
a=['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
b=['a', 'b', 'c']

powdata=open("powdata.txt","w")
for val in zip(a,b):
    powdata.write('{}, {}\n'.format(val[0], val[1]))
powdata.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming they are all the same length, use an index variable to pull the right entry from each. Here's the gist:

```
for i in len(a):
   print(a[i], b[i], c[i])
```